# How to replace a value in column A where column B is equal to value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, conditional-statements

I want to replace the start of a string (the first 5 characters) with nothing in column A if the value in Column B is equal to VendorA. I am not getting any further then replacing a value without the condition as mentioned above.

I have tried the following code:

```
    ColumnA    Vendor
1    A          ABBC/1234
2    B          BCCD/1234           
3    B          1234
4    C          1234ABBC/

Dataset.ColumnA= Dataset.ColumnA.replace(regex=['ABBC/'], value='')
```

```
#This should be the output

    ColumnA    Vendor
1    A          1234
2    B          BCCD/1234           
3    B          1234
4    C          1234ABBC/
```

Comment: `Dataset['ColumnA'] = Dataset.ColumnA.str.replace('^ABBC/', '')`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo it's probably better to write `Dataset['ColumnA'] = Dataset['ColumnA'].str.replace('^ABBC/', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':['A','B', 'B', 'C'], 'Vendor':['ABBC/1234','BCCD/1234','1234','1234ABBC/']})
>>> cola = ''.join(df['ColumnA'].values.tolist())
>>> df['Vendor'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Vendor'].split('/')[1] if row['Vendor'].startswith(cola) else row['Vendor'], axis=1)
>>> df
  ColumnA     Vendor
0       A       1234
1       B  BCCD/1234
2       B       1234
3       C  1234ABBC/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the '/' and use `np.where` to specify only on 'A'.

```
df['Vendor'] = np.where(df['ColumnA'].eq('A'), df['Vendor'].str.split('/').str[1], df['Vendor'])
```